# Google Maps Spiderfy open by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Looking to utlize the spiderfy which George MacKerron has developed. However I have one other requirement which is to load the map with all markers "spiderd" out by default. I can mimic this by using javascript to click on the markers, but there has to be another way by using the spiderfy code. Has anyone accomplished this?

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier#overlapping-marker-spiderfier-for-google-maps-api-v3

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {keepSpiderfied: true});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vFAy6/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developer of this google map extension this will not work.

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/issues/2

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a solution that worked for me. After I've added all markers, I set a timeout to call a functiont to open each cluster and in the OMS js.

1. keepSpiderfied keeps all spideried markers open. It wasn't working for me so I altered the OMS js. If it works for you, you don't need to change this.

Find this:

```
(!e||!this.keepSpiderfied)&&this.unspiderfy();
```

Replace with this:

```
(!e||!this.keepSpiderfied);
```

2. function to call to open each cluster group:

   ```
   function openAllClusters() {
       var markers = oms.markersNearAnyOtherMarker();

       $.each(markers, function (i, marker) {
           google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
       });
   }
   ```
3. I set a timeout after I added my last marker (because it didn't work just calling the function immediately after):

   `setTimeout(openAllClusters, 2000);`

Comment: Hello Shevy, would you happen to have a working example of this? I attempted to get it working with the following: http://paste.debian.net/170473/ but markers are not expanding upon page load. I replaced  (!e||!this.keepSpiderfied)&&this.unspiderfy(); with (!e||!this.keepSpiderfied); in the OMS js, and then added the function in step 2 to my html page. The setTimeout was placed at the end of my script.

Comment: **Note** that this might trigger infoWindow popup (since the marker click invocation)

Comment: Hi, is this supposed to keep the markers spiderfied even though the map is clicked? If not, do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation:](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier#overlapping-marker-spiderfier-for-google-maps-api-v3)

> keepSpiderfied (default: false)
>
> By default, the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier works like Google Earth, in that when you click > a spiderfied marker, the markers unspiderfy before any other action takes place.
>
> Since this can make it tricky for the user to work through a set of markers one by one, you > can override this behaviour by setting the keepSpiderfied option to true.

Comment: yeah I had tried that. But that constructor option doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Do you have example code or a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: For some reason my set up never works inside of jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/vFAy6/5/